# knockout not updating observable after AJAX call?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a standard ajax call that I call from here:

```
dataservice.createCard(card, function(serverData) {
    var newCard = new cardViewModel(serverData);
    // I see the right cardId here - from the server
    var index = innerModel.cards().indexOf(card);
    if (index !== -1) {
       // this gets hit but the DOM doesn't change
       innerModel.cards()[index] = newCard;
    }
}
```

In my view I have this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: data().cards -->
     <p data-bind="text: cardId"></p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Right now when I click "Add Card", I insert a blank cardViewModel into the list of cards.  When the user clicks save, I post back to the server and when the server responds to the async call, in the callback I try to replace the old "template" with the real data.

The problem is - the real data is never updating, unless I refresh the page.  If I set the initial cardId to some string, that string remains after I get real data, when it should turn into an Id.

What am I missing?

My innerModel mapping:

```
var mapping = {
    create: function (options) {
        //customize at the root level.  
        var innerModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {
            'cards': {
                create: function (options) {
                    var card = new cardViewModel(options.data);
                    return card;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

If there's anything else I should be including here, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
innerModel.cards()[index] = newCard;
```

with

```
innerModel.cards.splice(index, 1, newCard);
```

the first line doesn't allow Knockout to know an update occurred.